# godot gdscript crouching system not playing correctly

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am trying to add a crouching mechanic to my game, but it won't let me uncrouch at all.

```
    var crouch = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Crouch"):
        speed = CROUCHSPEED
        if !crouch:
            $AnimationPlayer.play("Crouch")
            crouch = true
    else:
        if crouch:
            var space_state = get_world_3d().direct_space_state
            var result = space_state.intersect_ray(PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(position, position + Vector3(0,2,0), 1, [self]))
            if result.size() == 0:
                $AnimationPlayer.play_backwards("Crouch")
                crouch = false
```

I have tried everything that I could think of to solve it like playing the crouch animation backwards, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll trim out your code to highlight the issue:

```
    var crouch = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Crouch"):
        # ...
    else:
        if crouch:
            # ...
```

As you can see `crouch` starts `false`. So it does not enter in the conditional `if crouch`.

To be clear, here `crouch` is a **local variable** of the method where you write this code. When the aforementioned method is not executing, the `crouch` variable does not exist, and therefore cannot have a value. We say that the variable is *scoped* to the method.

*To be more precise, if the method were executing multiple times (for example, if the method calls itself recursively, or if it was executed from multiple threads) each execution of the method would have its own local variable with its own value.*

---

Ok, let us look at the first part of the code:

```
    var crouch = false
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Crouch"):
        speed = CROUCHSPEED
        if !crouch:
            $AnimationPlayer.play("Crouch")
            crouch = true
```

Again, `crouch` starts `false`. So if the action `"Crouch"` is pressed, it will always enter the conditional `if !crouch`. I don't that is what you meant.

Instead, you could to keep track of the crouching state with an **instance variable** (a.k.a field). Instance variables are *scoped* to the instance※ and thus will retain their value across multiple executions of your method.

So you would declare `crouch` outside of the method (the guideline is to do it before the methods, near the top of the file):

```
var crouch := false
```

※: For example the `Node` where the script is attached. More precisely each instance that has the script attached would have its own instance variable with its own value.

---

By the way, I don't see you change the value `speed` other than here:

```
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Crouch"):
        speed = CROUCHSPEED
```

I don't know how you handle that. You could do something like the following *after* the code you have shown:

```
    if crouch:
        speed = CROUCHSPEED
    else:
        speed = NORMALSPEED
```